# Class of JDK can not be resolved in build.gralde file in Intellije Idea?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

When I import Spring Framework source code into Intellij Idea, gradle build task run successfully. But I find build.gralde file in Intellij Idea show some error like bellow. [image: some error in build.gralde file in Intellij Idea] Why String class can not resolved, the Test Unit can run successfully. How can I fix this.

Comment: May you share the whole build.gradle? Does it help to reset caches (**File | Invalidate caches and restart**)?

Comment: Thanks. I reset caches. It still not work.   The whole build.gradle is here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.16.RELEASE/build.gradle

Comment: What Gradle version and Java is in use? https://i.imgur.com/tH8dVwN.jpg

Comment: JDK version is 8 and  Gradle version is 2.14.1